# Select table row from map. Angular / Google Maps integration

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps

I have a table made by angularJS ng-repeat. How can I programmatically highlight(setSelected) one of my rows when I click a marker which is in map?
Here's my table:

```
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Line ID</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="linesList" ng-repeat="line in lines | orderBy: 'line_id'" ng-click="setSelected($event, line.line_id)" ng-class="{selected : line.line_id === line_id}">
                        <td>{{line.line_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{line.line_type}}</td>
                        <td>{{line.line_color}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/52hfonsq/

Comment: I think you have to change the class, put it on the `td` rather than the `tr`, i think your code looks right to me. You could always create a plnker and then I can take a look there

Comment: I can select and highlight a row in this table. But I want to highlight one of rows when I click a button out of this table.

Comment: Make that button change a `selected` poroperty on the model then. Make plnker and I can show you

Comment: Wow, that is quite a rewrite! I suggest you revert this question to the original table selection/button problem and create a new question for Angular / Google Maps integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see demo here   http://jsfiddle.net/7w6gh4we/1/

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            console.log(marker);


            $scope.safeApply(function () {
            $scope.idSelected = marker.line_id;
        });

            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });


 $scope.safeApply = function (fn) {
        var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
        if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
            if (fn && (typeof (fn) === 'function')) {
                fn();
            }
        } else {
            this.$apply(fn);
        }
    };
```